# HTML table parsing in swift

Tags: html, swift

I am trying to parse below HTML text to get data from   tag

```
<table class=\"table table-condensed\">

   <tr>
  <td colspan =\"2\">
 <h4>New Company</h4>
  </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>application</td>
  <td>web</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>server_name</td>
  <td>news.com</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td colspan =\"2\">
 <h4>Internal Machine</h4>
  </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>IP</td>
  <td>1.1.1.1</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>MAC</td>
  <td>AC:87:87:87:87:87</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td colspan =\"2\">
 <h4>External Machine</h4>
  </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>IP</td>
  <td>217.16.26.161</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td> Location</td>
  <td>test</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td colspan =\"2\">
 <h4>Additional Information</h4>
  </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>Amount Sent</td>
  <td>00.0 B</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>Amount Received</td>
  <td>2.5 KB</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>Application</td>
  <td>web</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
  <td>Ports</td>
  <td>12345, 123</td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `I am trying` Where's your code? Show us.

Comment: You want parse HTML to String right ?

Comment: @mitulmarsonia : yes, i am trying to get values from every tr td tag

Comment: what should be the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following libraries to help you parse HTML in Swift:

- [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)
- [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi)
- [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple)

For example, this can extract all TD values in your HTML using Kanna (code not tested):

```
let html = "<html>...</html>"

if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

    for td in doc.css("td") {
        print(td)
    }
}
```